# Proof that ${n - k \choose x}/{n \choose x} \leq (1 - x/n)^{k}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $n,k,x$ be positive integers such that $x \leq n-k$ and $k < n$.

Prove that $\frac{n - k \choose x}{n \choose x} \leq (1 - \frac{x}{n})^{k}$.

I've managed to prove a somewhat different result $\frac{n - k \choose x}{n \choose x} \leq (1 - \frac{k}{n})^{x}$, which is slightly different from what I'm trying to prove, but I'm pretty sure what I'm trying to prove is actually true. I'm not sure how to go about it.

Another claim which I also believe to be true, is that the LHS of the claim converges to the RHS as $n \rightarrow \infty, x/n \rightarrow 1$, although my concern is proving the bound and not the convergence.

Comment: My answer proves both - the bound and the fact that the limit is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:
I added a proof that the
ratio of the two expressions
tends to $1$.

Another fiddling with factorials and
looking for products of size $k$.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{n - k \choose x}{n \choose x}
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{(n-k)!}{x!(n-k-x)!}}{\dfrac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}}\\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{(n-k)!}{(n-k-x)!}}{\dfrac{n!}{(n-x)!}}\\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{(n-x)!}{(n-k-x)!}}{\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}}
\qquad\text{Bring things }k \text{ apart together}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-x-j)}{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)}\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{n-x-j}{n-j}\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1-\dfrac{x}{n-j})\\
&\lt\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1-\dfrac{x}{n})
\qquad \dfrac{x}{n-j} \gt \dfrac{x}{n}
\implies (1-\dfrac{x}{n-j})\lt 1-\dfrac{x}{n}\\
&=(1-\dfrac{x}{n})^k\\
\end{array}
$

---

The ratio of the two expressions
as $n$ gets large is

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1-\dfrac{x}{n-j})}{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1-\dfrac{x}{n})}
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{1-\dfrac{x}{n-j}}{1-\dfrac{x}{n}}\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{1-\dfrac{x}{n}+\dfrac{x}{n}-\dfrac{x}{n-j}}{1-\dfrac{x}{n}}\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1+\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{n}-\dfrac{x}{n-j}}{1-\dfrac{x}{n}}\right)\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\dfrac{\dfrac{xj}{n(n-j)}}{1-\dfrac{x}{n}}\right)\\
&=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\dfrac{xj}{(n-j)(n-x)}\right)\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\dfrac{xj}{(n-j)(n-x)}\right)\\
&\lt\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\dfrac{x}{(n/2)^2}\right)
\qquad\text{for } n>\max(2k, 2x)\\
&=\left(1-\dfrac{x}{(n/2)^2}\right)^{k-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\ln(1-z) < -z$,
$m\ln(1-z) < -mz$
so
$(1-z)^m < e^{-mz}$
so,
for large enough $n$,

$\begin{array}\\
\left(1-\dfrac{x}{(n/2)^2}\right)^{k-1}
&\lt e^{-4(k-1)x/n^2}\\
&\lt \dfrac1{1-4(k-1)x/n^2}
\qquad e^{-z} < 1-z \text{ for } 0 < z < 1\\
&\lt 1+8(k-1)x/n^2
\qquad 1/(1-z) < 1+2z \text{ for } 0 < z < 1/2\\
&\to 1\\
\end{array}
$